# Embedding of a category $\mathcal{C}\to\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ is an equivalence implies $\mathcal{C}$ has absolute colimits.

Tags: category-theory

Let $\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ be the category with objects $(c,e)$, where $c$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$ and $e:c\to c$ is idempotent.  A morphism $(c,e)\to(c',e')$ is the morphisms $f:c\to c'$ such that $f=e'\circ f\circ e$.

The embedding sends $c$ to $(c,1_c)$, and a morphism goes to itself.

I want to show that if the embedding is an equivalence, then $\mathcal{C} has all absolute colimits.

I was able to show that an absolute colimit in $\text{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$ is a retract of a representable.

My idea was to show that every absolute colimit is an idempotent splitting in $\text{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$, then try to argue that it is in $\overline{\mathcal{C}}\cong\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: If the idempotent completion is an equivalence, then every idempotent already splits in the original category. So a retract of any representable is representable.

Comment: @ZhenLin I should have clarified.  I intended the question to assume nothing but the embedding of $\mathcal{C}$ into $\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ is an equivalence.  I only called it "idempotent completion" in the title of the question because I didn't want to just write $\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ without any sort of mention of what it is.  Here, all I know is that it is the category defined in the body of the question.  Does that change/clarify anything?

Comment: Well, then you should prove that if $\mathcal{C} \to \bar{\mathcal{C}}$ is an equivalence then every idempotent in $\mathcal{C}$ splits.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for your help.  If I show that every idempotent in $\mathcal{C}$ splits, how do I conclude that $\mathcal{C}$ has all absolute colimits?  I need to show that an absolute colimit is an idempotent splitting somehow, is that correct?  Also, to show that every idempotent in $\mathcal{C}$ splits, I consider an idempotent $e:c\to c$ (and I will call the embedding $E$), then $E(e):(c,1_c)\to(c,1_c)$.  What maps can I use to get a splitting?

Comment: You already know that every absolute colimit is a retract of a representable. If idempotents in $\mathcal{C}$ split, then retracts of representables are representable. Show this, then it follows that $\mathcal{C}$ has absolute colimits. To show that idempotents in $\mathcal{C}$ split, first show that idempotents in $\bar{\mathcal{C}}$ split.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you.  I think I understand now.  Last question:  If $\phi:(c,e)\to(c,e)$ is an idempotent, then is the splitting given by $\phi$ and $(c,\phi)$?  Since $e\circ\phi=\phi=\phi\circ e$, $\phi$ is a morphism $(c,e)\leftrightarrows(c,\phi)$, and $\phi\circ\phi=\phi$ is the identity on $(c,\phi)$.  Is that even sensible?

Comment: Yes, that seems right. The idea is that $(c, e)$ represents the result of splitting the idempotent $e : c \to c$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you, what should i do with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarise my comments.

1. First you should show that $\bar{\mathcal{C}}$ is an idempotent-complete category, i.e. every idempotent in $\bar{\mathcal{C}}$ splits.
   The idea is that an object $(c, e)$ in $\bar{\mathcal{C}}$ represents the result of splitting the idempotent $e : c \to c$.
2. Since $\mathcal{C} \to \bar{\mathcal{C}}$ is assumed to be an equivalence of categories, $\mathcal{C}$ is also idempotent-complete.
3. Therefore any retract of any representable presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$ must also be representable.
4. You have shown that every absolute colimit is a retract of a representable presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$, so it follows that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under absolute colimits.